# Hadoop: MutipleInput functions not working

Tags: hadoop

I can't seem to get the MultipleInputs function to read in 2 separate files for processing. The output file always appear blank. I tried studying and debugging by referring to sample codes online but it can't seem to work.

```
public static class Mapper1 extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> 

{           
        private Text word = new Text();
        private final static Text identifier = new Text("a");

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());

            while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(itr.nextToken());
                    context.write(word,identifier);
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reducer extends
            Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        private IntWritable commoncount = new IntWritable();


        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int count1 = 0;
            int count2 = 0;

            for (Text val : values) {
                    if(val.equals("a")) 
                        count1++;
                else if(val.equals("b")) 
                    count2++;

            }
            if (count1 != 0 && count2 != 0)
                    context.write(key,new IntWritable(count1 <= count2 ? count1: count2));
            }
        }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException, ClassNotFoundException {

        Configuration conf = new Configuration();

        Job job1 = new Job(conf, "Testing");
        job1.setJarByClass(CommonWords.class);

        job1.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job1.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job1.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job1.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job1.setReducerClass(reduce.class);
        job1.setMapperClass(Mapper1.class);
        job1.setMapperClass(Mapper2.class);
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[0]), KeyValueTextInputFormat.class, Mapper1.class);
        MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job1, new Path(args[1]), KeyValueTextInputFormat.class, Mapper2.class);

        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job1, new Path(args[2]));
        job1.waitForCompletion(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `Mapper2` class ?

Comment: Hi there, Mapper2 class is exactly the same as Mapper1 but the text is set to "b" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these lines from your code and execute. Because you should not specify any mapper classes when you use MultipleInputs

```
job1.setMapperClass(Mapper1.class);
job1.setMapperClass(Mapper2.class);
```